# baked texture are black at edges

Tags: texture-baking

how to fix dark edges in baking process? i tried to disable denoising
Is there something else i can try?
here is the [file](https://asset.cloudinary.com/recapdataebse/5a2ed4267839a9d311f69c668f9aae90)

[image: black edges]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems:

- some objects have duplicated vertices. Select the object, switch to *Edit* mode, and remove the duplicated vertices by a <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*
- there are overlapping faces in the meshes (Screenshot 1 (1)). Delete them.
- there are extra faces that overlap the faces of neighboring objects. Delete them, too. (Screenshot 1 (2))
- objects are too close and create overlapping faces, that create black areas ("shadows") in the baked texture (Screenshot 1 (3)).
- UV islands are smaller than a pixel and the color cannot be baked properly. This results in the black areas in the green material. (Screenshot 2 (4)). Consider unpacking the 3D model again with a different mapping type that gives the UV island more texture space and doesn't waste so much.
- Cycles uses the denoiser when a texture is baked. The denoising seems to be too aggressive at the margins. I got better results when I disabled the *Denoise* option, disabled *Noise Threshold*, and used 500 *Max Samples*.

Screenshot 1:
[image: screenshot 1]

Screenshot 2:
[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: perfect it backed as i wanted... if you can suggest some tools that can do this job because it consume time as there are will be more complex meshs inside

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have some margin:

[image]

You will also need to have adequate resolution and space in-between UV islands for that margin to work. Unwrap operator also has option for margin for this:

[image]

Comment: it just make the texture overflow the uv map